# c++ class structure

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am writing a class to represent a pool of securities to be used in a portfolio selector. Depending on the objective metric and constraints, the class objects will cache some relevant data for performance optimization.

This could be done by defining a base class containing the common elements and its sub classes, each optimized for a particular objective metric/constraints.

But, I want the ability to cache data for multiple metrics. Is there a standard/neat way to do this?

Edit:

```
class Pool {
    // Contains data for different financial securities
}

class PercentileLossPool : public Pool {
    // Contains data which makes calculating percentiles easy
}

class AvgProfitPool : public Pool {
    // Contains data which makes calculating averages easy
}
```

This class structure makes it possible to have objects optimized for particular metrics (percentile, average)

What I want to build is an object which is optimized for multiple metrics, without writing code for all permutations

Comment: It's very hard to convey a software architecture with only words. I don't know about everybody else, but "a pool of securities to be used in a portfolio selector" doesn't mean much to me. Can you provide some code or perhaps a diagram to make it clearer?

Comment: @sftrabbit: You're not alone

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I have added some explanation.

Comment: Would PercentileLossPool still calculate averages, and AvgProfitPool still calculate percentiles, just without the caching optimization? Or will each subclass only do it's specific job and nothing else?

Comment: Each class calculates the metric it has been optimized for.

Comment: Take a look at the Strategy Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider reversing the relationship, by adding data to your class through inheritance:

```
class PoolBase {
     // Contains data for different financial securities
};

class PercentileLossData {
    // Contains data which makes calculating percentiles easy
};

class AvgProfitData {
     // Contains data which makes calculating averages easy
};

template< typename... Ts >
class Pool : public PoolBase, Ts...
{
};

typedef Pool< PercentileLossData, AvgProfitData > MyPool1;
```

But without further information on the specific problem you have it's hard to give advice that works. So, take the above as an idea, but be aware that there are multiple other options depending on your use-case.